# Loop through multiple PHP generated DIVs with show/hide on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I just set up the following jQuery code and it's working fine, however I have a feeling it can be refined into a much shorter loop with a counter. I am just familiar enough with jQuery to know this is a possibility but get stuck on the syntax etc. Thank you, and let me know if you need more specifics.

```
  $(".moviethumb:eq(0)").on("mouseover",
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(0), .hoverarrow:eq(0)").show();
    $(".moviedetail:eq(1), .moviedetail:eq(2)").hide();
  }
  );

  $(".moviedetail_wrapper:eq(0)").on("mouseleave", 
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(0), .hoverarrow:eq(0)").hide();
  }
  );

  $(".movieout:eq(0)").on("mouseout", 
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(0), .hoverarrow:eq(0)").hide();
  }
  );



  $(".moviethumb:eq(1)").on("mouseover",
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(1), .hoverarrow:eq(1)").show();
    $(".moviedetail:eq(0), .moviedetail:eq(2)").hide();
  }
  );

  $(".moviedetail_wrapper:eq(1)").on("mouseleave", 
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(1), .hoverarrow:eq(1)").hide();
  }
  );

  $(".movieout:eq(1)").on("mouseout", 
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(1), .hoverarrow:eq(1)").hide();
  }
  );



  $(".moviethumb:eq(2)").on("mouseover",
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(2), .hoverarrow:eq(2)").show();
    $(".moviedetail:eq(1), .moviedetail:eq(0)").hide();
  }
  );

  $(".moviedetail_wrapper:eq(2)").on("mouseleave", 
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(2), .hoverarrow:eq(2)").hide();
  }
  );

  $(".movieout:eq(2)").on("mouseout", 
  function () {
    $(".moviedetail:eq(2), .hoverarrow:eq(2)").hide();
  }
  );
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="movies-holder">

<li>

<a href="#">
<div class="movieout"></div>
<div class="moviethumb">
    <img src="theimage.jpg />
    </div>
</a>

<div class="moviedetail_wrapper">
<div class="hoverarrow"></div>
<div class="moviedetail">
<p>The movie details.</p>
</div>

</div>
</li>

<li>

<a href="#">
<div class="movieout"></div>
<div class="moviethumb">
    <img src="theimage.jpg />
    </div>
</a>

<div class="moviedetail_wrapper">
<div class="hoverarrow"></div>
<div class="moviedetail">
<p>The movie details.</p>
</div>

</div>
</li>

<li>

<a href="#">
<div class="movieout"></div>
<div class="moviethumb">
    <img src="theimage.jpg />
    </div>
</a>

<div class="moviedetail_wrapper">
<div class="hoverarrow"></div>
<div class="moviedetail">
<p>The movie details.</p>
</div>

</div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".moviethumb").on("mouseover",
   function () {
      var index = $(".moviethumb").index(this);
      $(".moviedetail, .moviedetail").hide();
      $(".moviedetail:eq(" + index + "), .hoverarrow:eq(" + index + ")").show();
   }
);

$(".movedetail_wrapper").on('mouseleave', function () {
   $(this).find('.moviedetail, .hoverarrow').hide();
});
```

`.movieout` can be handled in a similar fasion as the first function.  Essentially, you can get the index you want to use dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using CSS.

1) Give all divs an unique id="movie321"

2) Generate CSS rule for each.

```
ul.movies-holder li { display: block; }
ul.movies-holder.show320 li.movie320 { display: block; }
ul.movies-holder.show321 li.movie321 { display: block; }
```

3) In onmouseover:

```
document.getElementById('movies-holder').className = 'movies-holder show321';
```

This is **way faster** than looping in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(".moviethumb").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(".moviedetail").hide();
    $(this).parents("li").find(".moviedetail").show();
});

$(".moviedetail_wrapper").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).parents("li").find(".moviedetail, .hoverarrow").hide();
});

$(".movieout").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).parents("li").find(".moviedetail, .hoverarrow").hide();
});
```

using `$(this).parents("li")` you are looking for ancestors that are

. Then finding the class within that parent. You don't need to iterate.